# JQuery Conflict causes file upload to fail

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a file upload which is working very well on my page.  I want to also use gesture based events `swipeleft` and `swiperight` from jQuery, but for some reason my file upload fails if I use these libraries:

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js
https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js
```

Jquery Code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<script>
$("#box").on("swiperight",function(){$('.active').prev().trigger('click');});
$("#box").on("swipeleft",function(){$('.active').next().trigger('click');});
</script>
```

File upload is working very well if I comment out the above two libraries, but then I'm not able to use the swipe feature.

The file upload part is handled through PHP form submit.  What am I doing wrong?

PHP Code:

```
<?php  
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){  
        $target= array();   
        $total = count($_FILES['file']['name']);    
        for( $i=0 ; $i < $total ; $i++ ) {
            $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
            if ($tmpFilePath != ""){ 
                $newFilePath = "./uploads/" . $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
                if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {
                    $target[$i]= $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

HTML Code :

```
<div class="card-container">
<div id="box"></div>
</div>
<form class="contact100-form validate-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input class="input100" type="date" name="date" placeholder="Enter Date">
    <input class="input100" type="file" multiple="multiple" name="file[]">
    <button class="contact100-form-btn" type="submit" name="submit">
        <span>
             Submit
         </span>
    </button>
 </form>
```

Comment: You need to show your code to get good answers:   the way you've linked the scripts and the file upload form.

Comment: i just added that

Comment: there is no error, other input fields are getting loaded after clicking submit button it just file upload is not happening....removing those two library = result in working file upload

Comment: are there any functions in those two library that's blocking the file upload ...or causing conflict with other library

Comment: Have a look at https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-seems-to-clobber-ability-to-upload-files-via-forms

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this is an issue with jQuery mobile and file uploads.

To fix, you need to add `data-ajax="false"` to the `<form>` tag.